# Regex matching text till second dot, html tags excluded

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match all the text from the beginning up to the second dot, to the exclusion of dots that are contained inside html tags.

The following regexp `/^([^\.]*[\.]){0,2}/` works fine if they are no HTML tags since it selects everything from the start till the 2nd dot.

However, when I have this :

```
<p><img src="example.image.com" alt="foo">Text. More text.</p>
```

I would like my regexp to stop at the 2nd occurrence of the text, and not at the dot between "image" and "com".

I also know that `\.(?![^><]*>)` will select all dots outside html tags but I really am struggling and I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: What do you want to select with your regex? `"Text. More text."` or `"<p><img src"example.image.com" alt="foo">Text. More text."` Also this isn't valid HTML -- `src"example.image.com"`

Comment: What would you want if you had `<p>Text.<img src"example.image.com" alt="foo">More text.</p>`?

Comment: in general, doing this is a [Bad Idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: The `=` signs has been added to my post. I want to select everything from the start, that is "`<p><img src"example.image.com" alt="foo">`Text. More text." (of course, there will be more text coming after, so `.*` is of no use).

Comment: [Obligatory link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4231382/471272).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(?:(?:(?:<[^>]+>)*[^<.]*)*\.){2}
```

```
(?:                  # start of non-capturing group
    (?:              # start of non-capturing group
        (?:          # start of non-capturing group
            <[^>]+>  # matches an HTML tag
        )*           # match any more tags
        [^<.]*       # matches a sequence of non-tag, non-dot characters
    )*               # match any more tags and non-dot characters
    \.               # match a dot
){2}                 # repeat all of the above again
```

Detailed explanation and demonstration [here](http://regex101.com/r/pZ7oZ5).

Comment: @user3549691 Explanation on the way.

Comment: I've tried the regexp. It works fine if `<p>Sample text.<img src"example.image.com" alt="foo"> Example.</p>`, stopping right before the `</p>` but it does not work if there's a space between `text.` and `<img>`

Comment: @user3549691 What flavor of regex are you using? It works fine here: http://regex101.com/r/dK8tT0